# Передача данных с Контроллер в Представление

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc, asp.net-core

Начал изучать MVC и столкнулся с проблемой получения данных из Контроллера. В контроллер отправляется форма

```
<form class="List_testForm" action="~/questions/list" method="post">
                                <h3 class="form_h3" id="@count">@count. @quest.questionText</h3>
                                <label><input type="radio" name="option" value="@quest.option1" /> @quest.option1</label><br>
                                <label><input type="radio" name="option" value="@quest.option2" /> @quest.option2</label><br>
                                <label><input type="radio" name="option" value="@quest.option3" /> @quest.option3</label><br>
                                <label><input type="radio" name="option" value="@quest.option4" /> @quest.option4</label>
                                <input name="correct" value="@quest.optionCorrect" hidden /><br>
                                <input type="submit" value="Проверить" />
                            </form>
```

На контроллер отправляются выбранная опция и правильный ответ, где они и сверяются. Назад хочу получить значение true или false чтобы уже дальше работать с скриптами. 
Решил использовать ViewBag

```
public IActionResult List(string option, string correct)
        {
            bool Check = false;

            if (option == correct)
                Check = true;

            ViewData["Message"] = "true";


            return View();
        }
```

После формы сразу же вызываю

```
<p>@ViewData["Message"]</p>
```

А в ответ получаю лишь ошибки

[image: Еррор]

Если создавать ViewBag внутри Представления - всё отлично работает. Прошу подсказать, как это исправить или передать другим способом. (Пока не попытался передавать значение в Представление а просто выводил его через return $""; - всё работало)

Ошибки при попытке одного из методов контроллера вернуть еще одну модель.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Код контроллера

```
public ViewResult List()
        {
            ViewBag.Title = "Сторінка з тестами";

            QuestionsListViewModel obj = new QuestionsListViewModel();
            obj.allQuestions = _allQuestions.Questions;
            obj.questCategory = "Питання";
            return View(obj);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Answear(string option, string correct)
        {
            List<string> countries = new List<string> { "Бразилия", "Аргентина", "Уругвай", "Чили" };


            return View(countries);
        }
```

Вывод моделей в Представлении

```
<h3>В списке @Model.Count элемента</h3>
    @foreach (string country in Model)
    {
        <p>@country</p>
    }

<div class="test_area_right">
                        @{
                            count = 1;
                            foreach (var quest in Model.allQuestions)
                            {
                                <form class="List_testForm" action="~/questions/list" method="post">
                                    <h3 class="form_h3" id="@count">@count. @quest.questionText</h3>
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="option" value="@quest.option1" /> @quest.option1</label><br>
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="option" value="@quest.option2" /> @quest.option2</label><br>
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="option" value="@quest.option3" /> @quest.option3</label><br>
                                    <label><input type="radio" name="option" value="@quest.option4" /> @quest.option4</label>
                                    <input name="correct" value="@quest.optionCorrect" hidden /><br>
                                    <input type="submit" value="Перевірити" />
                                </form>

                                count++;


                            }
                        }
                    </div><!-- Test Area Right -->
```

Comment: Почему бы не передать в модель?

Comment: Можно поподробней? Я ничего не могу найти об этом. У меня четыре цикла заполняют формы данными из БД. Если я правильно понял, вы предлагаете записывать результат проверки в контроллере в отдельное поле вопроса. Как это сделать? Как потом к нему обращаться? Буду крайне признателен за максимально подробный ответ. Я только начал разбираться и мало чего умею)

Comment: `return View()` - `View` принимает модель (любой объект). Например это будет `List<Message>`. Потом в представлении останится забрать ее так: `@model List<Message>`.И дальше юзать так: `Model.` < Это и есть ваш `List<Message>`, который вы передали. [вот ссылка на пример](https://metanit.com/sharp/aspnet5/7.3.php)

Comment: Я уже передаю модель с всеми моими вопросами в View(); при старте страницы. Если я дописываю еще один метод в контроллере, что возвращает Модель - у меня выбивают ошибки, мол нигде нету определения методам из первой модели и List<string> не содержит их. Прикрепил ошибки, что появляются

Comment: Вы скидываете ошибки, но не показываете код...как Вам помочь? На сколько я вижу у вас во `View` не передается модель.

Comment: и если вам надо узнать корректный ответ или нет, я бы воспользовался `ajax` и `partialView` или `Json`

Comment: Обновил вопрос, добавив Код

Comment: Json: при добавлении библиотеки web.mvc многие пространства имен и методы отваливаются и подчеркиваются. partialView не выводит в конце, появляются точно такие же проблемы, что и на скрине с List<string>